If/else condition in gitlab-ci is not working
I have a gitlab-ci like this :
include:
  - project: templates/gitlab-templates
    file: sorush.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - build
  - release
  

variables:
  OKD_REGISTRY_BALY: "registry.apps.internal.okd.eu-central-1.cloud.baly.app"
  OKD_REGISTRY_BALY_STAGING: "registry.apps.internal.okd.eu-central-1.cloud.baly.app"

  OKD_PROJECT_BALY: baly-dpn-blitz
  OKD_PROJECT_BALY_STAGING: baly-dpn-blitz
  
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_API_BALY: "api_baly_latest"
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_API_BALY_STAGING: "api_baly_staging"
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_FEATURE_BALY_UPDATE: "feature_update_baly_latest"
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_FEATURE_BALY_UPDATE_STAGING: "feature_update_baly_staging"
  
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME: 'gitlab-ci'
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: ${OKD_BALY_TOKEN}
  OKD_CONSOLE_URL: https://api.okd.eu-central-1.cloud.baly.app:6443

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY 
  script: |
      if [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^staging.*$ ]]; then
        echo "Building staging...."
        docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} --file api_baly_dockerfile.dockerfile .
        docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} --file api_baly_dockerfile.dockerfile .
        docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
        docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
      elif [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^v.*$ && "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
        echo "Building production...."
        docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} --file api_baly_dockerfile.dockerfile .
        docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} --file api_baly_dockerfile.dockerfile .
        docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
        docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
      fi
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /staging.*$/'
      when: always 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /v.*$/'
      when: always 



.release-cloud: &release-cloud

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /staging.*$/'
      when: always 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /v.*$/'
      when: always 
  image: docker:dind
  stage: release
 

  before_script: 
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" =~ ^staging.*$ ]]; then docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}; docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}; fi
    - if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" =~ ^v.*$ ]]; then docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}; docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}; fi
    - docker logout $CI_REGISTRY


  script: |
    
    if [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^staging.*$ ]];  then
      docker login -u ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME} -p ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${OKD_REGISTRY} 
      docker tag ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_API_BALY_STAGING}
      docker tag ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly_staging_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_FEATURE_BALY_UPDATE_STAGING}
      docker push ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_API_BALY_STAGING}
      docker push ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_FEATURE_BALY_UPDATE_STAGING}

    elif [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^v.*$ && "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
      docker login -u ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME} -p ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${OKD_REGISTRY} 
      docker tag ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:api_baly_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_API_BALY}
      docker tag ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:feature_update_baly${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_FEATURE_BALY_UPDATE}
      docker push ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_API_BALY}
      docker push ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE_TAG_FEATURE_BALY_UPDATE}
    fi
  
 


Release (baly):
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: ${OKD_BALY_TOKEN}
    OKD_REGISTRY: ${OKD_REGISTRY_BALY}
    CONTAINER_REGISTRY_IMAGE: "$OKD_REGISTRY_BALY/$OKD_PROJECT_BALY/$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
  <<:

*release-cloud
and I want to tag some parts of the script based on my tagging in GitLab. like when a tag like git tag v1.0.1 in develop branch do this part :  elif [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^v.*$ && "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; and if I tag like git tag staging.v1 do that part :
if [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^staging.*$ ]]; but it doesn;t work. what it hthe problem with that ? i dont have error like but the message is like below  :

Login Succeeded $ if [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^staging.*$ ]]; then #
collapsed multi-line command Cleaning up project directory and file
based variables 00:01 Job succeeded


Syntax seems correct to me. Am i reading this correctly, that you are trying to run the pipeline after tagging the develop branch? ("$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "develop")
